# Delete whatsapp messages of a particular number programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am creating an app where user can delete all history of a particular number or group of numbers. I am able to delete calls and sms was just thinking if there a way to delete message/chats related to a particular number from whatsapp pragmatically in android. As whatsapp is also a popular source now. Any views/directions would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that WhatsApp is Sharing some kind of ContentProvider with other Apps. That would imply that all apps could read WhatsApp messages, which no User really wants. To read SMS, you have to apply the permission. There is no permission for WhatsApp I see so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

WhatsApp is a third party app, and does not provide an API for you to edit their data. On a rooted device you may be able to gain access to their databases, by they are AES encrypted, and you will have a tough time editing them on the fly.

Comment: how do you know about AES Encryptions of the WhatsApp DB?

Comment: @RafaelT I've worked with WhatsApp previously on stuff like this.

Comment: can't believe that an app that in the past refuses to use HttpS and "ecrypts" messages with a `SECRET_KEY` XOR now resorts to "real" encryption... Maybe I'll should have a closer look, if it is usable now. Anyway, thx for that info

Comment: @RafaelT They've made a lot of improvements recently. But their AES isn't top quality. The key is hard coded into the app, and it is possible to crack the encryption on the chat backup they put on the SD Card. I'd rather not disclose all this on a question. Perhaps we could take this to chat if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to other app. But if your device is root, you can access to database of Whatsapp